# Android reacts to a headset button press with a lag or not at all

Tags: headset

I have cheap wired headphones by JBL which have one button. The Huawei smartphone runs on Android 9. Audio apps react to a button press with a lag and sometimes don't react at all. I couldn't notice any pattern in their malfunctioning.

I'll appreciate advice.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It turned out that Google Assistant prevented the button signal to be read by other apps. Turning off Google Assistant didn't help. I had to turn off a device in a list of devices used by Google Assistant.

Comment: How did you manage to do that? turning off "use this device to talk to Assistant" switch in assistant settings did nothing regarding other apps not reacting to the headphones button..